# How to show Text and Json in Android

Tags: android, json

I want to develop android application for one website and I want read website posts from `json` and show then in `RecyclerView`. 
 I want show image ( **`<img>`** ) into `TextView`! My mean has show Text and Image in `TextView`.
**Json :**

```
"content": "<p>\u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. <\/p>\n<p><img src=\"http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/home_press_blog_15-300x200.jpg\" alt=\"home_press_blog_15\" width=\"300\" height=\"200\" class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-2326\" srcset=\"http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/home_press_blog_15-300x200.jpg 300w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/home_press_blog_15-768x512.jpg 768w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/home_press_blog_15-1024x683.jpg 1024w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/home_press_blog_15-219x146.jpg 219w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/home_press_blog_15-50x33.jpg 50w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/home_press_blog_15-113x75.jpg 113w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/home_press_blog_15.jpg 1200w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" \/><\/p>\n<p>\u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. <\/p>\n<p><img src=\"http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/05\/home_press_blog_7-300x200.jpg\" alt=\"home_press_blog_7\" width=\"300\" height=\"200\" class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-2310\" srcset=\"http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/05\/home_press_blog_7-300x200.jpg 300w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/05\/home_press_blog_7-768x512.jpg 768w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/05\/home_press_blog_7-1024x683.jpg 1024w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/05\/home_press_blog_7-219x146.jpg 219w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/05\/home_press_blog_7-50x33.jpg 50w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/05\/home_press_blog_7-113x75.jpg 113w, http:\/\/kolony.ir\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/05\/home_press_blog_7.jpg 1200w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" \/><\/p>\n<p>\u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. \u0627\u0648\u0644\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0622\u0632\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u0628\u0648\u0637 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062f \u0648 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06cc. <\/p>\n",
```

I want show text and image (`<img>`) into of **Content** (`json object`).

How can I show image and text in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to parse json data from online and display the image or some text in your recycler view

1. get your json data and parse it to a model. To do that you can use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library with retrofit gson converter. you can reference here [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) for descriptions of how. It handles all the parsing and mapping of the json data to a POJO.
2. assuming that you got the json data from your web/api and mapped to your model(done by retrofit) which is probably like.

   ```
    public class SomeModel{
                           .
                           .
                           .
               public String imagUrl;
               }
   ```

you can capture that and pass it to your recycler adapter. [Here](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/) is a nice tutorial on how to use recyclers.

3. once you got the model passed with the url parameter use [picasso (by square)](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [glide (by bumptech)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started), both great image libraries to display your image onto the image view. what they basically do is take the url of the image and load it into the image view taking care of all the hustle for you.

Answer (score 0):

TextView shows text, not html.  You can get it to show some basic styling like bold and Italic, but it will not display images.  If you need that, you need a WebView.

Comment: Thanks my friend. can you help me for this issue ? because I am amateur. I save this `jsonObject` (Content) into **dataModel**, how can I fetch this from **dataModel** and show into `webView`? can you help me? please my friend <3